# Calculate covariance of two images in matlab

Tags: image, matlab

I am doing a project on image quality assessment. I converted the image to grayscale & divided the entire image into 8x8 matrices using mat2cell function. I did this for two images, and now I want to calculate covariance between these two images (i.e the covariance between the matrix of image 1 and covariance between the same matrix of image 2). Note that both are the same images: one a pure image without distortions and one with distortions.

Comment: can you just convert your images to matrix (with grayscale values) and then do covariance?

Answer (score 1):

First convert your image to matrix:

```
I = double(imread('photo.jpg'));
```

then calculate covariance:

```
x=cov(I);
```

Comment: I converted the image to grayscale & divided the entire image into 8x8 matrices using mat2cell function , I did this for two images , now i want to calculate covariance between this two images i.e the covariance between the matrix of image 1 and covariance between the same matrix of image 2 . note that both are the same images one a pure image without distortions and one with distortions

Answer (score 0):

For single matrix input, C has size [size(A,2) size(A,2)] based on the number of random variables (columns) represented by A. The variances of the columns are along the diagonal. If A is a row or column vector, C is the scalar-valued variance.

For two-vector or two-matrix input, C is the 2-by-2 covariance matrix between the two random variables. The variances are along the diagonal of C.